# Flex 4.6 Popup Menu using ItemRenderer and RadioButton

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, radio-button, itemrenderer, flex4.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:VGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
      width="300" height="300" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"     xmlns:cc="cc.*">
<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import cc.SimpleRadioButtonRenderer;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable]public var mydataProvider : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ 
            {label:'United States of America',data:0},
            {label:'Alabama',data:1},
            {label:'Alaska',data:2},
            {label:'Arizona',data:3},
            {label:'Arkansas',data:4},
            {label:'California',data:5},
            {label:'Colorado',data:6},
            {label:'Connecticut',data:7},
            {label:'Delaware',data:8},
            {label:'Florida',data:9},
            {label:'Georgia',data:10},
            {label:'Hawaii',data:11},
            {label:'Idaho',data:12},
            {label:'Illinois',data:13},
            {label:'Indiana',data:14},
            {label:'Iowa',data:15},
            {label:'Kansas',data:16},
            {label:'Kentucky',data:17},
            {label:'Louisiana',data:18},
            {label:'Maine',data:19},
            {label:'Maryland',data:20},
            {label:'Massachusetts',data:21},
            {label:'Michigan',data:22},
            {label:'Minnesota',data:23},
            {label:'Mississippi',data:24},
            {label:'Missouri',data:25},
            {label:'Montana',data:26},
            {label:'Nebraska',data:27},
            {label:'Nevada',data:28},
            {label:'New Hampshire',data:29},
            {label:'New Jersey',data:30},
            {label:'New Mexico',data:31},
            {label:'New York',data:32},
            {label:'North Carolina',data:33},
            {label:'North Dakota',data:3},
            {label:'Ohio',data:35},
            {label:'Oklahoma',data:36},
            {label:'Oregon',data:37},
            {label:'Pennsylvania',data:38},
            {label:'Rhode Island',data:39},
            {label:'South Carolina',data:40},
            {label:'South Dakota',data:41},
            {label:'Tennessee',data:42},
            {label:'Texas',data:43},
            {label:'Utah',data:44},
            {label:'Vermont',data:45},
            {label:'Virginia',data:46},
            {label:'Washington',data:47},
            {label:'West Virginia',data:48},
            {label:'Wisconsin',data:49},
            {label:'Wyoming',data:50},
        ]);

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:List id="menulist" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{this.mydataProvider}" >
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
                <s:RadioButton value="{data.label}"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
</s:VGroup>
```

I am having a lot of issues with this new Spark Component. All I'm trying to do is make a MXML custom control that will be popped up (from within a view in a mobile app) since there is no popup menu list or drop down combo (the ones there are dead right ugly) when a certain control is tapped. The popup contains a list populated with radiobuttons.

I have tried using the {data} as the label property but I keep getting the error 
"1120: Access of undefined property data."

Can anyone help me with this please?